# How to check the Ping and Port connectivity for multiple host from source machine?

Tags: php, shell

Can any one help me get script for checking ping and port connection for multiple host.

```
<?php
echo "testing ";
function ping($host)
{
    exec(sprintf('ping -c 1 -W 5 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
    return $rval === 0;
}
$host = 'www.google.com';
$up = ping($host);

if($up)
echo "success";
else
echo "Failure";

?>
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with python?

Comment: I am try to writing the code in linux system.

Comment: i can use Python script to implement the same, using the dictionary multiple IP address